# Como colocar a média na última table no Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

pessoal eu tenho a seguinte dúvida esse meu código ele incrementa para sempre que tiver uma avaliação ele mostra, mas, a media sempre fica após como se fosse uma nota

```
<% @registration.matrix.blocks.each do |block| %>
    <h5>Bloco: <%= block.description %></h5>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered shadow-sm">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Disciplina</th>
                <th>Faltas Atribuidas</th>
                <th>Prova 1</th>
                <th>Prova 2</th>
                <th>Prova 3</th>
                <th>Prova 4</th>
                <th>Prova 5</th>
                <th>Prova 6</th>
                <th>Prova 7</th>
                <th>Prova 8</th>
                <th>Prova Final</th>
                <th>Média</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% block.disciplines.distinct.each do |discipline| %>

            <tr>
                <td><%= discipline.name %></td>
                <td>
                    <%= number_of_absences(current_user, discipline) %>
                </td>
                <% discipline.evaluations.each do |evaluation| %>
                    <td><%= Evaluate.get_evaluate(current_user.id, evaluation.id).present? ? Evaluate.get_evaluate(current_user.id, evaluation.id).note : '0,0' %></td>
                <% end %>
                <td><%= get_media(current_user, discipline) %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Então gostaria de saber como eu faço para arrumar o erro, por exemplo eu coloquei a nota 10, ele divide por 8 conforme eu programei, mas a média que é 10/8 já que 10 foi a unica nota que atribui, ela fica 1,25 porém a media fica do lado e não no final, como eu faço para colocar no final na table "média"

[image: Conforme é visto na imagem seguinte]

Answer (score 0):

O resultado da média não está aparecendo no final porque você precisa que a quantidade de `<th></th>`  seja  a mesma quantidade de `<td></td>`.

No seu exemplo você 12 `<th>` tags e somente 3 `<td>`.

Você deve sempre deixar a mesma quantidade e no seu caso você vai precisar a medida que for colocando as notas (prova -> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, final)

```
      <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered shadow-sm">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Disciplina</th>
                    <th>Faltas Atribuidas</th>
                    <th>Prova 1</th>
                    <th>Prova 2</th>
                    <th>Prova 3</th>
                    <th>Prova 4</th>
                    <th>Prova 5</th>
                    <th>Prova 6</th>
                    <th>Prova 7</th>
                    <th>Prova 8</th>
                    <th>Prova Final</th>
                    <th>Média</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% block.disciplines.distinct.each do |discipline| %>

                <tr>
                    <td><%= discipline.name %></td>
                    <td>
                        <%= number_of_absences(current_user, discipline) %>
                    </td>
                    <% discipline.evaluations.each do |evaluation| %>
                        <td><%= Evaluate.get_evaluate(current_user.id, evaluation.id).present? ? Evaluate.get_evaluate(current_user.id, evaluation.id).note : '0,0' %></td>
                    <% end %>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><%= get_media(current_user, discipline) %></td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: cara até "funcionou" acontece que quando eu atribuo a segunda nota, ai pula e buga kkkk

Answer (score 0):

Usa o "times" para fazer um laço das vezes que tem repetir o , sendo a diferença entre 8 e o tamanho das notas.

```
<% discipline.evaluations.each do |evaluation| %>
<td><%= Evaluate.get_evaluate(current_user.id, evaluation.id).present? ? Evaluate.get_evaluate(current_user.id, evaluation.id).note : '0,0' %></td>
<% end %>
<% (8 - discipline.evaluations.length).times do %>
  <td></td>
<% end %>
```

só não sei se fica "bonito".